# variant changes when I pass it to function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter a range in VBA then pass it to a function as a variant object.

First, I define the object and assign it as follows:

```vb
Dim wRows As Variant 
ActiveSheet.range("A:Z").AutoFilter 1, "W"
Set wRows = ActiveSheet.range("B9:l7000").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

I see the object in my debugger as I would like it.
[image: wRowsObject as seen in debugger]

If I transfer the range to a function as follows:

```
copyWiederkehrend (wRows)
Public Function copyWiederkehrend(all As Variant)
    MsgBox ("HALLLLO")
End Function
```

the object in the debugger looks like this:
[image: all object as seen in debugger]

A lot of data is lost.

I defined the object as a range, object or as a variant, nothing works.

Comment: It should be `copyWiederkehrend wRows`. I can't see why you wouldn't pass it as a `Range` though.

Comment: why without the brackets? but yes now it looks the same in debugger.

Comment: Because that's the correct syntax. ;) You only use brackets if you are using `Call`, *using* the result of a function, or explicitly trying to evaluate an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to a Subroutine in VBA can be done either with

```
copyWiederkehrend wRows
```

or with

```
Call copyWiederkehrend(wRows)
```

Both commands are identically (some state that it is deprecated to use `Call`, but that's a different story).
If you call a Function and you are *not* interested in the result that is returned, the syntax is exactly the same. If you *want* to get the result of the function, syntax is

```
x = copyWiederkehrend(wRows)
```

But when you write

```
copyWiederkehrend (wRows)
```

the parenthesis around (wRows) are *not* used to show the VBA runtime the list of parameters. They are interpreted as *"get the value of"* (note that now a space is between the function name and the rest of the command).

Writing a statement like `x = 3 * (y + 2)` will do something similar: The runtime will calculate `y + 2` and put this intermediate result somewhere into the memory, multiply it by 3 and ultimately pass this result to `x`. The point is that once the intermediate result is calculated, it is no longer associated with `y`. The same happens when you write `x = 3 * (y)` - the intermediate result contains the same value as `y`, but it is a copy of that value.

You can check this by passing a variable as parameter to a function *by reference* and then modify the value within the subroutine:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim v As Long
    v = 3
    testSub v
    Debug.Print v   ' This will print 4
    
    v = 3
    testSub (v)
    Debug.Print v   ' This will print 3
End Sub

Sub testSub(ByRef x As Long)
    x = x + 1
End Sub
```

In the first case, the value of `v` changed (because it was passed by reference). In the second case, an intermediate *copy* of `v` was passed and modified.

Now putting a Range into parenthesis will do something unusual: It will use the *Default* property of the Range object. You often see statements like `x = Range("A1")` in VBA (for Excel), and you don't think about it - you take it for granted that x will receive the *Value* of the cell A1. But if you think about it, it is not really easy to see what goes on. `Range("A1")` is an object of type `Range` with lots of properties, so why is the *value* assigned to `x` (and not, for example, the color, the width, the font size or number format)? This is because in VBA objects can have default properties that are used if you don't specify something: Writing `x = Range("A1")` is similar to `x = Range("A1").Value`.

So if your range `wRows`contains only one cell, (wRows) will create a single value that then is passed as parameter. If it contains more than one cell, it will create a 2-dimensional array of values - that is what you see in your case in the debugger. Again, note that those values are no longer associated with the range, so if you modify them in the subroutine, they will not be written back into Excel.

One hint: As long as your work with `Ranges` (and not with the values stored in that range), you should declare your variables as `Range`, not as `Variant`.

```
Dim wRows As Range
Set wRows = ActiveSheet.range("B9:l7000").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 

copyWiederkehrend wRows     ' This is okay
copyWiederkehrend (wRows)   ' Will throw an error.

Public Function copyWiederkehrend(all As Range)
    MsgBox ("HALLLLO")
End Function
```

Why this is throwing an error? Because (wRows)  will create 2-dimensional array of values, and that is no longer a `Range` and therefore an error occurs (in this case "424- Object is required). Don't avoid this errors by converting everything to `Variant` - basically the runtime tells you that you did something wrong and that's a good thing.